# Is it possible to have a constant valued through a Spring Service?

Tags: spring, web-services, static, singleton

We have a web service that one of its parameters is called origin and this origin is always validated against a code in the database.

For each one of our services I have to validate this code. This code does not change so I want to keep it in a constant, but I still have to validate it to prevent clients from sending a wrong code.

Basically what I want is this:

```
@Service
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private LogBS logBS;

    // I know this cannot be used in a static context.
    public static final Long CODE = this.logBS.retrieveLogWebServiceCode("webServiceName");

    public void validateOriginCode(final Long origin) {
        if (!origin.equals(CODE)) {
            throw new ServiceException("Wrong origin code!");
       }
   }
}
```

I know something similar can be done with Spring caching, but is it possible to do it with a constant?

Comment: why don't you create an immutable class which holds the constant and initialize it in the `@PostConstruct` of the `Service` class?

Comment: @yaswanth Can you post an answer showing how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather go with this:

```
@Service
public class CodeValidatorService {

    private LogBS logBS;

    private Long CODE;

    @Autowired
    public CodeValidatorService(LogBS logBS){
        this.logBS = logBS;
        CODE = this.logBS.retrieveLogWebServiceCode("webServiceName");
        if (CODE == null){
            throw new ServiceException("Code cannot be read from DB!");
        }
    }

    public void validateOriginCode(final Long origin) {
        if (!origin.equals(CODE)) {
            throw new ServiceException("Wrong origin code!");
       }
   }
}
```

Just as a code review, I prefer injecting dependencies in the constructor rather than using `@Autowired` in the field directly, it makes the service testable. You could also try to read the code in a `@PostConstruct` method, but I think it's better to do it in the constructor so you always have the service in a ready-to-go state.

For using it in the rest of your services, inject the `CodeValidatorService` instance on them:

```
@Service
public class OtherService {

    private CodeValidatorService codeValidatorService;

    @Autowired
    public OtherService(CodeValidatorService codeValidatorService){
        this.codeValidatorService = codeValidatorService;
    }

    public void performAction(final Long origin) {
        codeValidatorService.validateOriginCode(origin);
        //do the rest of your logic here
   }
}
```

**See also:**

- [Spring Beans and dependency injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html)
- [Setter injection versus constructor injection](https://spring.io/blog/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required/)

Comment: This way I cannot have CODE available for all the other `@Service`s.

Comment: Answer changed.

Comment: Great answer. Since Spring Beans are Singletons I'll have the query performed only once as I intended autowiring the dependencies with the constructor approach. I'll use my attributes with final keyword as well.

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea. For me, the best thing of using Spring for singletons instead of implementing singletons yourself is that you can easily test them (it's easy to mock `CodeValidatorService` with this implementation, to force it to return an exception, for example) and the impl is far more readable.

Comment: I personally do not code without Spring anymore for several reasons. Code readability and testability are two of them.

Comment: what would you recommend if I want to `"webServiceName"` also parameterized in this constructor considering that I have this name in a enum entry?

Comment: Philippe, please post a different (detailed) question for this

Answer (score 1):

You can have a constantsProvider class

```
@Component
public class ConstantsProvider {

    @Autowired
    private LogBS logBS;

    private String CODE;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        CODE = this.logBS.retrieveLogWebServiceCode("webServiceName");
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return CODE;
    }
}
```

Add this snippet of code to `Service` class

```
@Autowired
private ConstantsProvider constantsProvider;
```

You can use `constantsProvider.getCode()` in your services. This way CODE is going to be immutable and not defined in a static context.

Note: If you have more constants similar to this, there is a better way to define the `ConstantsProvider` class. If there is only one, I would stick to the above implementation.

Edit 1:

If you need it in all the service classes, make the constantsProvider a spring bean and initialize the `CODE` there itself. Updated the answer

Comment: This way the init method has to be written in all services or some kind of Service hierarchy has to bring thought. What would be the better way to define ConstantsProvider?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Basically the same approach as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes. The accepted answer seems to be better. I didn't find it clear enough in the question that you need to have this constant across all the services.

Comment: I still appreciate your effort in helping!